# Is my proof correct? I'm slightly confused about complete induction. (Spivak Calculus, problem 2-7)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

**Theorem.** $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^p$ can always be written in the form $\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1} + An^p + Bn^{p-1} + Cn^{p-2} + \cdots$

*Proof.* We will prove by complete induction on $p$. For the base case, notice that the theorem is true for $p = 1$, since $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{1}{2}n^2 + \frac{1}{2}n.$ Next, suppose the theorem is true for all natural numbers less than or equal to $p$. To begin, we expand the binomial $(k+1)^{p+2}$ using the binomial theorem. That is,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(k+1)^{p+2} = k^{p+2} + \binom{p+2}{1}k^{p+1} + \binom{p+2}{2}k^{p} + \cdots + \binom{p+2}{p+1}k + 1 \\[3pt]
(k+1)^{p+2} - k^{p+2} = \binom{p+2}{1}k^{p+1} + \binom{p+2}{2}k^{p} + \cdots + \binom{p+2}{p+1}k + 1. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Adding for $k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, we have 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(n+1)^{p+2} - 1 &= \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{p+2}{1}k^{p+1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{p+2}{2}k^{p} + \cdots + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{p+2}{p+1}k + n \\[3pt]
(n+1)^{p+2} &= \binom{p+2}{1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p+1} + \binom{p+2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p} + \cdots + \binom{p+2}{p+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k + n + 1 \\[3pt]
(n+1)^{p+2} &= \frac{(p+2)!}{(p+1)!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p+1} + \frac{(p+2)!}{2!p!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p} + \cdots + \frac{(p+2)!}{(p+1)!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k + n + 1 \\[3pt]
\frac{(n+1)^{p+2}}{p+2} &= \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p+1} + \frac{p+1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p} + \cdots + \sum_{k=1}^{n}k + \frac{n+1}{p+2} \\[3pt]
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p+1} &= \frac{(n+1)^{p+2}}{p+2} - \frac{p+1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p} - \cdots - \sum_{k=1}^{n}k - \frac{n+1}{p+2}. \\[3pt]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
For the final step, I will add the terms of the series, and generalize the coefficients. 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p+1} = \frac{(n+1)^{p+2}}{p+2} + An^{p+1} + Bn^p + Cn^{p-1} + Dn^{p-2} + \cdots$$
We have proven $Q(p+1)$. The induction step is thus complete, and we can conclude that the theorem is true for all natural numbers $p$. $\Box$

---

I have tried to make my writing as clear as possible, so I apologize if anything is unclear. Any tips on improving clarity would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi i-cant-name, this looks correct, The only thing I would change is be slightly more clear how you are using the induction hypothesis at the end. So "For the final step we use the induction hypothesis to write $\sum^{n}_{k=1}k^{m}=P_{m}(n)$ where $P_{m}$ is a polynomial of degree $p+1$. Adding the terms and generalizing the coefficients gives us:"